# How to use/run a speech recognition c# application run in a remotely connected system?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, speech-recognition, system.speech.recognition

I have created a speech recognition application using C#. 
When I run the application in a remote system with mic connected to my system, it doesn't work. So is there a way we can achieve running the application in a remotely connected system with mic connected to your own system?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you created the speech recognition application you should be able to refactor it to a client/server architecture. You can either decide to process the audio on the client and only send structured messages to the server or stream the raw audio from client to the server.

Comment: I created a Speech Recognition application using System.Speech.Recognition.
If I have to stream the raw audio from client to server, then how can I do that?
I mean as of now, if I run the application with speech recognition in a server it gives me an exception as no input device(in my case - mic) is connected. It actually starts looking for Mic/Input device in that server.